# Variable of index in an R loop

Tags: r, for-loop, variables, statsmodels

I don't really know how to explain this so I put the code directly it will be more clear :

```
modeledir = "/data/modeles/modele"
for (numero in (df["CLE"] %>% unique())){
  df2 <- df[df["CLE"] == numero,]
  [...]
  if (something > 0) {
    [...]
    nom <- paste(modeledir, numero, sep = "-")
    saveRDS(object = modelemain, file = nom)
  }
}
```

I have an error because of the numero variable of the for loop that is not the numero but ALL the numero, so `paste(modeledir, numero, sep = "-")` return :

```
[1] "/data/modeles/modele-name1"
[2] "/data/modeles/modele-name2"
[3] "/data/modeles/modele-name3"
[4] "/data/modeles/modele-name4"
```

instead of : `"/data/modeles/modele-name1"`

I don't understand how it's possible and more than that when I do my things he selected well the subset of `df` that rows very column CLE is name1.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Try changing to `for (numero in (df[["CLE"]] %>% unique())){` (Using `[[` instead of `[`). `df["CLE"]` is 1-column data frame, but `df[["CLE"]]` is just the vector.

Comment: Also, when using loops in R, the sintax would be something more like ´for numero in 1:df[[... ` . Be aware that you need to explicitly mention the first value of the counter of the loop

Comment: Hey very thanks to both of you that function well, I didn't know about those things :)